# What textBox event to use after swiping a credit card in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Example: after I swiped the credit card the value will be displayed on `textBox1` and what I want to happen is that the focus will be automatically go to `textBox2`.

What Textbox event should I use for this?

Thanks!

Here is the screenshot I use the textchange event and im using a testcard
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the Text Changed event, but only focus the next textbox if you got all the information you need on the current one (i.e all digits were entered)

```
private void TxtBox1TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtBox1.Text.Length == LENGTH_OF_CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER)
    {
        txtBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

I suggest setting a max length to txtBox1 and then checking:

```
if (txtBox1.Text.Length == txtBox1.MaxLength)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think all credit card number is not in the same length

Comment: Then you can have a timer of 100ms that is restarted every TextChanged, and when the 100ms is reached it runs and stops itself and moves focus. In simple words: Delay the focus change..

Comment: It'll be best if you could identify the card type by it's data, which sounds logical that you could, and then check if the number of characters is the # of digits that is associated with that card type. Timers are usually dirty.